# How to manage different settings for each customer?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

We have 1 settings file with the customer settings for each costumer, but the problem is that we have to change lots of settings values when releasing a new version for each costumer, as we develop using the test settings. So, its a totally mess.

Whats the best solution for this? 
Having one settings file and app.config for each costumer? 
Saving the configurations into the database?(we would still have the connection string settings)

Each costumer cant see the settings from the others..

Comment: why do the settings change? Normally you have the default-values in the settings/app.config, the customer changes those and you just don't override the customers file (why would you?)

Comment: Our output is a executable setup file. 
We use some webservices, and each costumer has one login and password for it, that are stored in the settings file.

Comment: You shouldn't store usernames and passwords in a settings file. You should store them in the database. Settings file can be tempered with and break your app or in the worst case scenario, enable malicious access to user accounts.

Comment: dont worry about this, its a wpf application used on touch screen monitors

Comment: 'dont worry about this' in relation to storing passwords  = famous last words.

Comment: OK. i can put all these settings to the database, but what about the connection string? how can i manage different connection strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a [Configuration Transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this and have multiple [Build (Release) configs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx) like

- Release-Internal
- Release-CustomerA
- Release-CustomerB

You can have one "base" config file and just replace the values you need for the specific configuration.

Your file structure would look like this afterwards

```
app.config
    app.Release-Internal.config
    app.Release-CustomerA.config
    app.Release-CustomerB.config
```

We usually use this for the connection strings and some specific view settings.

Visual Studio only has nativ support for ASP.NET projects (for whatever reason), but there are multiple Plugins to enable this for other .NET projects.

I can recommend [Configuration Transform](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859) (I like this one better) or [SlowCheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5).